# matrices en python, como hacer para que me diga si existe un camino o no entre dos lugares

Tags: python, bucle-for, matrices, numpy

tengo un proyecto de la universidad en python que consiste en seleccionar dos departamentos y formar una matriz con cada uno de sus municipios despues, el usuario ingresara dos de los municipios y el programa le dira si existe un camino directo o no, solo tengo la matriz pero no se como seguir

```
#esta es la matriz, los vectores que faltan como por ejemplo [0,0] significa que no existe camino 
directo
import numpy as np
N=18  #Número de vertices
matriz_ady = np.zeros( (N,N), dtype=int)  #se declara la matriz de adyacente

#matriz de adyacente
matriz_ady[0,3] = 1
```

- matriz_ady[0,6] = 1 matriz_ady[1,6] = 1 matriz_ady[1,12] = 1
  matriz_ady[1,13] = 1 matriz_ady[1,14] = 1 matriz_ady[2,3] = 1
  matriz_ady[2,4] = 1 matriz_ady[2,10] = 1 matriz_ady[3,0] = 1
  matriz_ady[3,2] = 1 matriz_ady[3,9] = 1 matriz_ady[3,10] = 1
  matriz_ady[4,10] = 1 matriz_ady[4,12] = 1 matriz_ady[4,13] = 1
  matriz_ady[5,7] = 1 matriz_ady[5,8] = 1 matriz_ady[5,11] = 1
  matriz_ady[5,17] = 1 matriz_ady[6,0] = 1 matriz_ady[6,1] = 1
  matriz_ady[6,9] = 1 matriz_ady[6,14] = 1 matriz_ady[7,5] = 1
  matriz_ady[7,11] = 1 matriz_ady[8,5] = 1 matriz_ady[8,16] = 1
  matriz_ady[8,17] = 1 matriz_ady[9,3] = 1 matriz_ady[9,6] = 1
  matriz_ady[9,14] = 1 matriz_ady[10,2] = 1 matriz_ady[10,3] = 1
  matriz_ady[10,4] = 1 matriz_ady[10,9] = 1 matriz_ady[10,12] = 1
  matriz_ady[10,14] = 1 matriz_ady[11,5] = 1 matriz_ady[11,7] = 1
  matriz_ady[12,1] = 1 matriz_ady[12,4] = 1 matriz_ady[12,10] = 1
  matriz_ady[12,13] = 1 matriz_ady[12,14] = 1 matriz_ady[13,1] = 1
  matriz_ady[13,4] = 1 matriz_ady[13,12] = 1 matriz_ady[13,15] = 1
  matriz_ady[14,1] = 1 matriz_ady[14,6] = 1 matriz_ady[14,9] = 1
  matriz_ady[14,10] = 1 matriz_ady[14,12] = 1 matriz_ady[15,1] = 1
  matriz_ady[15,4] = 1 matriz_ady[15,13] = 1 matriz_ady[15,16] = 1
  matriz_ady[15,17] = 1 matriz_ady[16,8] = 1 matriz_ady[16,15] = 1
  matriz_ady[16,17] = 1 matriz_ady[17,5] = 1`` matriz_ady[17,8] = 1
  matriz_ady[17,15] = 1 matriz_ady[17,16] = 1

  ## imprimimos la matriz de adyacencia

  print(' MATRIZ DE ADYACENCIA :')

  print('') print(matriz_ady)

Comment: No logro entender muy bien cono funciona loq ue estas haciendo. Lo que quieres es cagar multiples municipios por departamento en una matriz?

Comment: hola, gracias por responder SI, son dos departamentos con municipios en una matriz, los que estan como por ejemplo [0,6], el primer valor corresponde a un municipio (0) y el segundo al otro(6) si esto es igual a 1 significa que existe un camino directo, el valor no esta en la matriz significa que no existe camino directo

Comment: Saber si hay un camino directo entre dos municipios es obvio. Supongo que lo que pides es trazar un camino posible entre dos municipios cualquiera. Existen muchos algoritmos de teoría de grafos, algunos mejor o peor, según sea la complejidad del problema. Los dos más conocidos: búsqueda en amplitud y búsqueda en profundidad. Explicarte estos temas se sale de los objetivos de este foro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para empezar, me imagino que tienes algo asi, esto es un ejemplo de 2 departamentos con 3 municipios:

```
depA = [[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]]

depB = [[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]]
```

Es un ejemplo abstracto, puedes tener mas, e incluso en vez de tener esos nuimeros puedes tener objetos de una clase llamada Municipio. El caso es que te recomiendo un consejos antes de que responda lo que debes hacer para encontrar el camino correcto

- **Utilizar diccionarios en vez de matrices:** En python existe la ventaja de que hay una estructura de datos llamada diccionarios de
  datos, o diccionarios. Su uso es muy sencillo y lo puedes mirar en
  menos de 5 minutos por Google. Basicamente esta estructura consiste
  en tupas de informacion, cada tupla tiene 2 valors, clave y valor. Es
  muy util para representar grafos porque puedo hacer que un vertice de
  mi grafo tenga una lista de los vecinos que lo conectan. Es muchisimo
  mas facil de recorrer. Si quieres puedes controlar todas las operaciones del grafo, como agregar nodos y conexiones con una clase, y que esa clase guarde el diccionario. El diccionario es muy flexible, y permite manejar los grafos de una manera mucho mas sencilla.

Ahora, respondiendo a tu pregunta hay algoritmos ya diseñados para encontrar caminos entre un vertice a otro dentro de una red de un grafo:

- **BFS:** Busqueda por anchura
- **DFS:** Busqueda por profundidad

Estos algoritmos, ademas de devolverte la ruta mas corta, tambien lo puedes modificar (no hay que hacerle mucho a los algoritmos para hacerle esto) para que te devuelvan una lista vacia en casode que no se haya encontrado un camino, o un mensaje que no se pudo encontrar un camino entre los vertices. Auque, como son municipios, hay una alta probabilidad de que todos esten conectados y no haya este problema, pero si lo queires implementar pues adelante.

> **NOTA:** Estos algoritmos devuelven el costo mas corto con respecto al numero de saltos, o menores vertices que haya.

Ademas de los algoritmos que te mencione, existen otros que tienen en cuenta el peso entre vertices, este peso es un costo de ir de un nodo a otro, como el tiempo, el costo de transporte, de gasolina, la distancia, entre otros. Estos algoritmos son:

- **UCS:** Busqueda por costo uniforme, es similar a los anteriores pero tiene en cuenta el costo, devolviendo el camino con menos costo con respectoa  los pesos entre aristas.
- **A*:** Es un algoritmo mas avanzado, puesto que tiene informacion previa del grafo, esta informacion es un conocimiento que le ayuda a tomar una mejor decision. Estos datos son llamados Heuristica. Esta heuristica puede ser la distancia de un nodo hacia los demas, el tiempo de un nodoa los demas, el numero de bajadas que debe hacer para llegar de un nodo hacia todos los demas, la distancia euristica de un nodo hacia los demas, entre otros.

De este ultimo se derivan otros algoritmos como el Greedy o voraz.

En conclusion, todos estos algoritmos te sirve, pero claro, deopende de tu caso te sera conveniente utilizar uno u otro. Si quieres algo de rapida imoplementacion y qye funcionara la mayoria de veces escoge BFS o DFS, o si quieres hacer una busqueda por costos tambien puedes implementar UCS. Si quieres implementar algo mas avanzado utiliza A* y sus derivados.

Si lo quieres dejar en matrices tambien lo puedes hacer, los algoritmos no cambian en absoluto, solo cambia la forma de implementarlos, pero el concepto sigue siendo el mismo.

**ACTUALIZACION:** Si necesitas ayuda con respecto de esto de grafos, hace poco realice un proyecto apra buscar el mejor camino en un sistema de transporte publico entre las estaciones de este. Mi codigo de esta en GitHub y lo puedes encontrar [Aqui](https://github.com/Garnica1999/SearchTransmilenioIA).

**ACTUALIZACION 2:** Debido a nuevas dudas, con la pregunta de como probar si los algoritmos que tiene implementados estan bien o mal, hay 2 maneras de verificarlos:

1. **El camino largo:** Probar tu algoritmo con tu problema actual, eligiendo manualmente en un papel el destino y final, y dibujando a mano, ademas de comparar con los resultados. Este metodo es un poco largo y engorroso si el problema es largo
2. **El camino corto:** Posiblemente es el que quieras tomar. Este es similar al primero, solamente que se prueban los algoritmos con grafos pequeños, para que la prueba de escritorio y las pruebas manuales sean mas cortas y no gasten tanto tiempo. Los resultados dados manualmente se comparan con los que da el algoritmo programado, de esta manera sabes si el algoritmo esta bien implmenetado para tu problema como para cualquier otro, o por lo menos para la mayoria.

Comment: ohh!! ya ya te cache, gracias por tu respuesta, investigare sobre eso y tratare de resolverlo, espero si me lo acepten asi, ya que el ingeniero creo que lo quiere con matrices si o si :(

Comment: de todo el laboratorio que nos dejo, lo que me falta es esto 
El usuario podrá seleccionar un municipio de origen y un municipio de destino, de manera que el
programa deberá indicar:
a. Si existe camino entre esos municipios (verificar Matriz C de Warshall)
b. Cual es la longitud del camino más corto (verificar Matriz de Caminos Mínimos)
c. Cual es el nodo intermedio para llegar del origen al destino (verificar Matriz T)

Comment: Pero ya tienes los algoritmos a utilizar, segun he leido.

PD: Tambien puedes utilizar las matrices con los algoritmos que dije en caso de que no haya restricciones.

Comment: si, osea las matrices con los algoritmos ya los tengo, ahora que lo pienso creo que quiza formule mal mi pregunta, en todo caso lo que no logro resolver es como hacer para verificar los datos de la matriz y decidir si hay o no hay camino

Comment: ALa verificacion tienes que hacerla a mano, no hay de otra. Tambien lo puedes hacer con software de mapas que hallan la ruta mas corta entre 2 puntos geograficos. Creo que google maps tiene esto pero realmente no estoy seguro de ello.

Comment: Lo que tambien puedes hacer y que se me acabod e ocurrir es probar estos algoritmos con grafos mas pequeños, de tal modo que lo puedas probar mas facilmente a mano y no tengas que hacer 80000 pruebas con el programa que tienes.

Comment: si, gracias por tu respuesta! espero estes bien! :D

Comment: Voy a actualizar mi respuesta teniendo en cuenta las dudas.